# How to declare project artifacts in non-Java build?

Tags: gradle

I have multi-project Gradle build that contains also non-Java projects.

I want to declare the artifacts create by one such project in a way that I can use project/configuration dependencies to get them, e.g.

```
consumer:
dependencies {
  myConf project(path: ':producer', configuration: 'myConf')
}
```

What I currently have is this:

```
producer:
configurations {
  myConf
}

task produceFile {
   //... somehow create the file...

   outputs.file file('path/to/file')
}

artifacts.add('myConf', produceFile.outputs.files.singleFile, { builtBy produceFile })
```

Is there a better way to declare the artifact than my clumsy version?

I couldn't figure out a way to pass the task dependency from the artifact to the producing task in one go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation article on [Legacy publishing](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_management.html) and the javadoc on the [`ArtifactHandler`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/ArtifactHandler.html), for your simple example it should be sufficient to just pass the task, as long as the task type extends `AbstractArchiveTask` (e.g. `Zip` or `Jar`):

```
artifacts.add('myConf', produceFile)
```

... or in the more Gradle-ish way:

```
artifacts {
    myConf produceFile
}
```

The article mentioned above has another example, where a `File` is passed directly to the `add` method, which requires you to specify the task to build the file in the way you did in your example.

However, let me propose other ideas for syntax that may be experienced more 'lightweight':

```
artifacts {
    myConf files(produceFile).singleFile { buildBy produceFile }
    // or
    myConf file: files(produceFile).singleFile, buildBy: [produceFile]
}
```

These two examples use the `Project.files(...)` method to resolve the output(s) of the task instead of accessing them manually. The second example makes use of the map syntax often provided by Gradle.

If you want to somehow standardize your way to publish your custom artifacts, I would propose to create a custom task type that offers any of the different arguments the `ArtifactHandler` can process as a method or property:

```
class MyTaskType extends DefaultTask {
    // ... other stuff ... of course this should be part of a plugin
    def getArtifact() {
        return ... // either a (Configurable)PublishArtifact (if constructor is available) or a map representation
    }
}

task produceFile(type: MyTaskType) {
    // configure somehow
}

artifacts {
    myConf produceFile.artifact
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
However, it seems that this only works for archive tasks, which is also stated in the doc for `ArtifactHandler` (https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/ArtifactHandler.html) 
Is there a way to do this for other tasks as well?
And I wasn't aware that this is the legacy way of declaring artifacts - I'll look into the new way as well, maybe my solution lies there.

Comment: Okay, I'm sorry I did not notice this part of the documentation. I edited my answer and added some more ideas.

Comment: Regarding the legacy question, as far as I know, only the old publishing plugin (`maven`) is considered legacy in favor of the new plugin (`maven-publish`). Even with the new plugin, you can use the `PublishArtifact` instances in your `ArtifactHandler` and I did not find any hint that those parts of the API are considered legacy or deprecated.

Comment: Great edit! I wasn't aware of that feature of `Project.files(...)` and that's exactly what I've been looking for. Also the map syntax probably helps with the closure as that was sometimes considered part of the second argument, causing errors.